# Casperjs: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function" if evaluate() is used in another file

Tags: javascript, casperjs

the following code ist working with casperjs 1.1.0-beta3 and phantomjs 1.9.8:

```
function getImage(locator, casper) {

return casper.evaluate(function(locator) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(locator), function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
},locator);

};    

casper.start("http://stackoverflow.com/", function () {

    var img = getImage('img[class="sponsor-tag-img"]', this);
    this.echo(img[0]);
    this.download(img[0], "logo.png");   

});

casper.run();
```

But if I split up the code into two files and call util.getImage() from the other file, the following error appears: `~/tmp/PhantomCSS $ casperjs test --web-security=no demo/stack.js`

```
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'util.getImage('img[class="sponsor-tag-img"]', this)')
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: demo/stack.js:5
#    error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'util.getImage('img[class="sponsor-tag-img"]', this)')
#           TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'util.getImage('img[class="sponsor-tag-img"]', this)')
#               at demo/stack.js:5
#               at runStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553)
#               at checkStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399)
#    stack: not provided
```

stack.js:

```
var util = require('/home/gauss/tmp/PhantomCSS/demo/util.js');

casper.start("http://stackoverflow.com/", function () {

    var img = util.getImage('img[class="sponsor-tag-img"]', this);
    this.echo(img[0]);
    this.download(img[0], "logo.png");   

});

casper.run();
```

util.js:

```
function getImage(locator, casper) {

    return casper.evaluate(function(locator) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(locator), function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('src');
        });
    },locator);

};
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how `require` works. It is very similar to the node.js type require.

You have two possibilities. For more information see the [docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html).

### `module.exports`

util.js:

```
function getImage(locator, casper) {
    // impl
}
module.exports = getImage;
```

stack.js:

```
var getImage = require('util'); // extension can be omitted
// use getImage(locator, casper)
```

This type is best suited for class functions or passing global objects to all functions, not for a collection of utility functions. A variant is:

util.js:

```
function getImage(locator, casper) {
    // impl
}
module.exports = function(casper){
    return {
        getImage: function(locator){
            return getImage(locator, casper)
        }
    };
};
```

stack.js:

```
var util = require('util')(casper); // extension can be omitted
// use util.getImage(locator)
```

### `exports`

util.js:

```
function getImage(locator, casper) {
    // impl
}
exports.getImage = getImage;
```

stack.js:

```
var getImage = require('util'); // extension can be omitted
// use getImage(locator, casper)
```

---

By the way, your `getImage` utility function is already available in CasperJS as [`getElementsAttribute`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsattribute):

```
casper.getElementsAttribute(locator, "src");
```